# is it unconventional to prefix a django app with _

Tags: django

prefixing Django apps with _ does seem to work but is it unconventional? Will it give problems?

exemple:

```
_login
_dashboard
_proxy
core
locale
static
templates
```

Comment: Yes, it's unconventional. Any reason you want to do this? Have you tried it and noticed any issues?

Comment: It's unconventional, right, but understandable: for example, I'd name some compatibility layer that is intended to monkey-patch something temporary like this. It should not produce any issues (but don't use *two* underscores, it may lead to crashes probably).

Comment: I tried it and encountered no problems. I thinks its clearer is see which folders are apps.